# How far apart should my bank statement date be and my application for spouse visa UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, uk-visa, banking, eu-spouses

I am preparing for my UK spouse visa application. Is there a minimum amount of time between me printing my official bank statement from the bank and submitting my application? I know I need to prove that the money's been in my account for 6 months and it's actually been in there for 9 months now, so I'm clear. But can I print a bank statement on the 15th of July then send in my application on the 20th of August, for example?

Answer (score 1):

While there is no specific minimum time frame, statements and other documents need to be proximate and current. Submitting an application with documents obtained within a reasonable time, a few days or weeks, is perfectly acceptable.